# Meta tag histories are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, meta, tag-wiki

Currently the history and excerpt history links go nowhere useful. The {postid} is missing from the link.

Comment: Shhh. They're sleeping.

Comment: For which tags? I don't see this...

Comment: @Shog9 See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info) for example.

Comment: Ah, ok. This appears to be a bug common to all child meta sites, for the handful of tags that are pre-populated on new metas.

Comment: Don't you just love community bug hunting!

Answer (score 5):

As Shog mentioned in the comments, this happens for the default tags that each child meta starts out with. Unfortunately, that's because the initial descriptions for those tags don't come from the database at all.

I pushed a change that disables the history links and adds a tooltip that explains that you're looking at the default initial revision and there's no other history to display in these cases. With you in the next production build.